# App not installed error after deleting class from manifest

Tags: android

**Problem :** I have uploaded an apk on google play store, then i have changed some code which is, deleted a service tag from manifest because i did not needed it more.

```
<service
   android:name=".Services.MyService"
   android:exported="false" />
```

I have removed above code from manifest but I didnot deleted my class from package ".Services" for future use and then i created a signed apk. I have done following things.

- Clean project , rebuild again.
- Checked V1 and V2 while generating Apk.
- Only checked V1 and generated Apk.
- Only checkd V2 and generated Apk.

Everything is fine, I have incremented build version and done every other thing which i found on internet but still got this error. [Please take a look on error received image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynbey.jpg)

Then I added service tag again in manifest and generated apk again. My issue resolved. Its strange, I want to know that why it happened? how i will handle if I made any change?
 and please check these images -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVNPZ.jpg  for my manifest, directories and exception which was seen in logcat during installation,.
  Thanks

Comment: show your manifest and code directories

Comment: Show you manifest.

Comment: @WaleedAsim please take a look for manifest and directories.  and also there was some error in logcat during installation.
https://imgur.com/a/xq3sH4Q

Comment: @PedroMassango Please take a look on my comment.

Comment: Found some answers there, follow this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589509/android-e-parcel-class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-only-on-samsung-tab3

Comment: @PedroMassango Thanks , but I have already visited this and got NO success.

Comment: Please show you service class

Comment: @PedroMassango , take a look -> https://imgur.com/a/fB5O4Ce

Comment: @ObaidJatoi here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889724/apk-cannot-install

Comment: @WaleedAsim thanks , your proposed solution worked for after reading articles related to V2 and V1 signatures.

Comment: @ObaidJatoi you welcome bro