# Cant generate signed apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

[image]I going to export my android App in Android Studio by Build -> Generate Signed APK but according to the below image, V1 & V2 checkboxes are disabled! what should i doing now!!?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648499/difference-between-signature-versions-v1jar-signature-and-v2full-apk-signat

Comment: Just Click on V2 no need to worry my friend

Comment: Post your gradle

Comment: your image attach  link is not working

Comment: Please post your image again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: I cant check checkboxes because they're disable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find my problem, the problem was because of Gradle and after update gradle problem goes away. :)