# Signature algorithm error while trying to upload apk to Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

When I try to upload my apk to the google play store I get the following error.

Upload failed

You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature. Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.RSA uses digest algorithm SHA-256 and signature algorithm RSA which is not supported on API Level(s) 16-17 for which this APK is being verified

Does anybody know how I can change the signature algorithm, or how to solve this error?

Comment: While generating signed apk check mark box having option v1 (jar signature) and uncheck v2  since v2 is for newer ones

Comment: This did not solve the problem

Comment: have tried cleaning , rebuilding project and creating and new .jks key? and then follow above procedure?

Comment: It worked now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That's great  I am posting it as an answer , kindly approve that so that other's can get benefit from it :)  #HappyCoding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating signed apk **check** option **v1 (jar signature)** and **uncheck** option  **v2** since v2  is for newer ones!

if it doesn't work then: Do  clean , rebuild project and create new .jks key and do the same!

For reference: [difference between signature versions - V1(Jar Signature) and V2(Full APK Signature) while generating signed apk in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648499/difference-between-signature-versions-v1jar-signature-and-v2full-apk-signat)