# Replacing apk file in play store after update to project

Tags: android, google-play

I have a question in regards to generating APK files and uploading them to google play store.

I have uploaded my apk currently in the play store. Now I sent my project to a developer to make some changes. When they send me the project back, I am guessing I will need to generate the apk signature again from android studio with the same keystore credentials as before.

If I do this and upload that apk to the playstore to replace the previous one, will the upload work or will there be a signature mismatch? I just want to know what's the correct procedure.

Thanks

Update:

So do I perform the following?

[image]

And then here do I keep the settings as is or do I untick the two tick boxes related to full apk signature and jar signature?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you generate the apk with the same keystore credentials as the one currently in the play store (you should not be creating new signature) it should be fine. It also has to have the same package name.

Comment: Can you see my update to see I have got it correct, going to show some screenshots

Comment: yep, the first image is correct. I haven't worked with different signature versions but i assume it creates separate files for each version. The full apk signature should be what you need for the play store if that's what you uploaded previously.

Answer (score 3):

Once you upload an app to the Play Store, the only thing you need to be sure of the next time you upload a new version, is to use the same Key Store with the same package.

Anyways if you don't do this, Play Store won't allow the key to be changed on an existing app. If you want to use a new key, you'll have to set it up as a new app on the Play Store.

The screenshot process you just uploaded is correct. For signature you leave the two boxes checked and if you have questions about differences between both signatures please read the following [difference between signature versions - V1(Jar Signature) and V2(Full APK Signature) while generating signed apk in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648499/difference-between-signature-versions-v1jar-signature-and-v2full-apk-signat)