# Generate signed APK - Signature version - What to choose?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

What to choose - V1 signature or V2? My app is for android 4+. So if I'll use signature version V2, can I install it on phones with android 4+. As I know V2 signature came out after Android 7 and I think that phones above android 7 can't install app, because of V2 signature. So what to choose? Can I choose both and what will be if I'll choose both signature versions? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between signature versions - V1(Jar Signature) and V2(Full APK Signature) while generating signed apk in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648499/difference-between-signature-versions-v1jar-signature-and-v2full-apk-signat)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688224/8738574

Comment: @medyas bro that link not gave me answer. I don't know will be app installed with signature version V2 above android 7?

Comment: check both to support apps with version lower then 7

Answer (score 4):

You should sign with both v1 and v2.

The v2 signature will be used on devices Android 7+, and the v1 signature will be used on the other devices. You could technically only sign with v1, but v2 is faster so your app installs faster on devices that support it.